# Can you implement Flink's AggregateFunction with Generic Types?

Tags: java, generics, interface, apache-flink

My goal is to provide an interface for a stream processing module in Flink 1.10. The pipeline contains an AggregateFunction among other operators. All operators have generic types but the problem lies within the AggregateFunction, which cannot determine the output type.

Note: The actual pipeline has a slidingEventTimeWindow assigner and a WindowFunction passed along with the AggregateFunction, but the error can be reproduced much easier with the code below.

This is a simple test case that reproduces the error:

```
    @Test
    public void aggregateFunction_genericType() throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.setParallelism(1);

        DataStream<Tuple2<String,Integer>> source = env.fromElements(Tuple2.of("0",1), Tuple2.of("0",2), Tuple2.of("0",3));

        ConfigAPI cfg = new ConfigAPI();

        source
                .keyBy(k -> k.f0)
                .countWindow(5, 1)
                .aggregate(new GenericAggregateFunc<>(cfg))
                .print();


        env.execute();
    }
```

As you can see, a Configuration class is passed as an argument to the Custom aggregateFunction. This is what the user would implement.

```
    public static class ConfigAPI implements BaseConfigAPI<Tuple2<String, Integer>, Tuple2<String,Integer>> {
        @Override
        public Tuple2<String, Integer> createAcc() {
            return new Tuple2<>("0", 0);
        }

        @Override
        public Tuple2<String, Integer> addAccumulators(Tuple2<String, Integer> in, Tuple2<String, Integer> acc) {
            acc.f1 += in.f1;
            return acc;
        }
    }
```

The provided interface is:

```
    public interface BaseConfigAPI<In, Acc> {
        Acc createAcc();
        Acc addAccumulators(In in, Acc acc);
        // other methods to override
    }
```

The GenericAggregateFunction:

```
    public static class GenericAggregateFunc<In, Acc> implements AggregateFunction<In, Acc, Acc> {

        private BaseConfigAPI<In, Acc> cfg;
        GenericAggregateFunc(BaseConfigAPI<In, Acc> cfg) {
            this.cfg = cfg;
        }
        @Override
        public Acc createAccumulator() {
            return cfg.createAcc();
        }
        @Override
        public Acc add(In in, Acc acc) {
            return cfg.addAccumulators(in, acc);
        }
        @Override
        public Acc getResult(Acc acc) {
            return acc;
        }
        @Override
        public Acc merge(Acc acc, Acc acc1) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The output log:

```
org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.InvalidTypesException: 
Type of TypeVariable 'Acc' in 'class misc.SlidingWindow$GenericAggregateFunc' could not be determined. This is most likely a type erasure problem. 
The type extraction currently supports types with generic variables only in cases where all variables in the return type can be deduced from the input type(s). 
Otherwise the type has to be specified explicitly using type information.
```

**Solution 1 (not working)**:
At first I thought this is the usual case of "return type cannot be determined" so I tried adding

`.returns(Types.TUPLE(Types.STRING, Types.INT))` after `.aggregate(...)` but without success.

**Solution 2 (working)**:
I created a Wrapper class with a generic type, named `Accumulator<Acc>` which is then passed as Type to the
`AggregateFunction<In, Accumulator<Acc>, Accumulator<Acc>>` and seems to be working.

This does not look very elegant though and it is not very consistent with the rest of the interface. Is there any other solution to this problem?

**Edit**: Thanks @deduper for your time and insight, I think I found a solution.

**Solution 3 (working)**: I created a new interface which extends my `BaseConfigAPI` and the `AggregateFunction` in the following manner:

```
public interface MergedConfigAPI<In, Acc, Out> extends BaseConfigAPI, AggregateFunction<In, Acc, Out> {}

public interface BaseConfigAPI extends Serializable {
    //These will be implemented directly from AggregateFunction interface
    //Acc createAcc();
    //Acc addAccumulators(In in, Acc acc);
        
    //other methods to override
}
```

Now the user must only implement the `MergedConfigAPI<In, Acc, Out>` and pass it as a parameter to the `.aggregate(...)` function.

**UPDATE**: I tested @deduper's 3rd solution against the framework and it didn't work either. It seems like the exception is thrown by the `Acc` and not the `Out` type. Taking a closer look at the internals of the `.aggregate` operator, I realized that there is an overloaded `aggregate` method that takes 2 more arguments. A `TypeInformation<ACC> accumulatorType` and a `TypeInformation<R> returnType`.

This is how the simplest solution emerged without any code refactoring.

**Solution 4 (working)**:

```
 @Test
 public void aggregateFunction_genericType() throws Exception {
                ...

                .aggregate(
                        new GenericAggregateFunc<>(cfg), 
                        Types.TUPLE(Types.STRING, Types.INT),
                        Types.TUPLE(Types.STRING, Types.INT))
                ...
    }
```

Note: As of Flink 1.10.1 the `aggregate` methods are annotated with @PublicEvolving.

Comment: To check that I understand correctly: The  _`SlidingWindow`_ referred to in your stack trace: „_`at misc.SlidingWindow.aggregateFunction_genericType(SlidingWindow.java:54)`_“ is the first bunch of code in your question? The _`@Test aggregateFunction_genericType()`_  method being the „*simple test case that reproduces the error*“. The error message says: „*...`Type` of `TypeVariable` '`Acc`' in 'class `misc.SlidingWindow$GenericAggregateFunc`'  could not be determined...*“. What type had you assumed _`Acc`_ was? And what line of code supports your assumption that _`Acc`_ should be that type?

Comment: @deduper Yes, the first code block corresponds to the one in the stack trace as you correctly understood. I had assumed `Acc` to be of type `Tuple2<String,Integer>`, but I could not support this assumption. Therefore, I tried initializing the `GenericAggregateFunction` before passing it as argument to the `.aggregate()` operator like this: `GenericAggregateFunc<Tuple2<String, Integer>, Tuple2<String, Integer>> aggregateFunc =  new GenericAggregateFunc<>(cfg);`. Does this addition support my assumption?

Comment: „*Thanks @deduper for your time and insight, I think I found a solution...*“ — UR Welcome Sir! & Thank ***You*** for sharing such an excellent problem. I learned a ton solving it. For my further education — *since I'm not running/testing* [*my solution*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_307208) *locally* — how does my most recent solution candidate do in your _`aggregateFunction_genericType()`_ test? I mean the one where I added the third type parameter: _`GenericAggregateFunc<In, Acc, Out>`_. Also, is my assumption correct that your *New Solution* takes its cue from my Q's last edit? Just curious.

Comment: @deduper Thank you :) I ended up not using your solution in my test because I decided to discard the `GenericAggregateFunc` altogether and let the _user_ implement it. However, all of your comments and edits contributed to the solution simply by questioning the correctness of the problem at every step.

Comment: „*...I ended up not using your solution in my test because I decided to discard the GenericAggregateFunc altogether...*“ — Yeah that's what I understood you to mean. But I was sorta-kinda asking for a favor: *Since I don't have the necessary framework installed locally (it would be inconvenient to) and since you already have the necessary framework installed, can you run please, the implementation I proposed to see how she goes?* Just intellectual curiosity mainly. More important than my curiosity, your response will narrow down or eliminate the options future askers will also consider. TIA.

Comment: @deduper Thanks again for your commitment! It seems like we found the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> „*Can you implement Flink's AggregateFunction with Generic Types?*“

Yes. You can. As you've done yourself already. Your error is a result of how you *used* it (*as in* „*use-site generics*“) rather than how you *implemented* it.

> „*...Is there any other solution to this problem?...*“

I propose the following three candidate solutions in ascending order of *simplicity*…

```
...
source
       .keyBy(k -> k.f0)
       .countWindow(5, 1)
       .aggregate(new GenericAggregateFunc< Tuple2<String, Integer>, Tuple2<String, Integer> >(cfg)) /* filling in the diamond will aid type inference */
       .print();
...
```

The above is the simplest because you wouldn't have to refactor your original *`GenericAgregateFunc`*; simply fill in the diamond with the specific type arguments you want to instantiate your generic class with.

There is also another slightly less simple solution…

```
public static class GenericAggregateFunc implements AggregateFunction<Tuple2<String, Integer>, Tuple2<String, Integer>, Tuple2<String, Integer>> {

    private BaseConfigAPI<Tuple2<String, Integer>, Tuple2<String, Integer>> cfg;
    GenericAggregateFunc(BaseConfigAPI<Tuple2<String, Integer>, Tuple2<String, Integer>> cfg) {
        this.cfg = cfg;
    }
    @Override
    public Tuple2<String, Integer> createAccumulator() {
        return cfg.createAcc();
    }
    @Override
    public Tuple2<String, Integer> add(Tuple2<String, Integer> in, Tuple2<String, Integer> acc) {
        return cfg.addAccumulators(in, acc);
    }
    @Override
    public Tuple2<String, Integer> getResult(Tuple2<String, Integer> acc) {
        return acc;
    }
    @Override
    public Tuple2<String, Integer> merge(Tuple2<String, Integer> acc, Tuple2<String, Integer> acc1) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Although this one involves a minor refactor, it *simplifies* your entire application more than the first proposed solution — *in my opinion*.

Flink already handles the „*complicated*“ Generic polymorphism for you. All *you* have to do, to plug-in to Flink, is *simply* instantiate their built-in generic *`AggregateFunction<IN, ACC, OUT>`* with the specific type arguments you want to instantiate it with. Those type arguments being of type *`Tuple2<String, Integer>`* in your case.

So you're still „*using Generics*“ with the second solution, but you're doing so in a much simpler way.

Another option closer to your original implementation, but with a couple minor refactors…

```
public static class GenericAggregateFunc<In, Acc, Out> implements AggregateFunction<In, Acc, Out> {
    
    ...
    @Override
    public Out getResult(Acc acc) {
        return ...;
    }
    ...
}
```

Also, to *force* the precondition that the user's config implements an interface that's compatible with your function…

```
public interface BaseConfigAPI< In, Acc, Out >{ ... }
```

In [*my experiment*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_307208) I've confirmed that adding the *`Out`* type parameter to *`BaseConfigAPI`* too, makes it compatible.

I did have a more *complicated* alternative solution in mind. But since simpler is almost always better, I'll leave that more complicated solution for somebody else to propose.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried the first solution myself as I stated in the comment above but it didn't work. Filling the diamond seems to be redundant. The second solution looks very logical and it definitely simplifies the code, but that means the user has to implement 2 interfaces instead of 1. BaseConfigAPI and the AggregateFunction.

Comment: Thanks @EdwardEp! — „*...the user has to implement 2 interfaces instead of 1. BaseConfigAPI and the AggregateFunction...*“ — It's not clear what you mean. So [*I did an experiment*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_307208) to try to figure it out. I copied the classes in your Q. But replaced your _`GenericAggregateFunc`_ class with the *simplified* one in my answer. To _use_ the simpler _`GenericAggregateFunc`_ class I simply instantiated it: _`GenericAggregateFunc simple = new GenericAggregateFunc()`_. ***Your class*** implements the Flink interface. The *user* just has to create your class. No?

Comment: Notice that the second code snippet `ConfigAPI` is implemented by the user, so I would not know beforehand what types he would use. Therefore, he should also implement Flink's `AggregateFunction` interface besides the `BaseConfigAPI`. This is what I mean by saying _"the user has to implement 2 interfaces"_. My goal was to have a generic implementation of the `AggregateFunction` which internally would call methods from the `BaseConfigAPI` interface. I feel like the solution is somewhere in the middle, I just can't grasp it yet.

Comment: Thanks @EdwardEp. What error do you get when you use the implementation of the _`GenericAggregateFunc`_ from my answer, in your _`SlidingWindow.aggregateFunction_genericType()`_ test?

Comment: When using your `GenericAggregateFunc` I get no errors, but its types are hardcoded to `Tuple2<String, Integer>`.

Comment: „*When using your GenericAggregateFunc I get no errors, but its types are hardcoded...*“ — Thanks @EdwardEp. I've edited my answer to add an alternative to the hard-coded type arguments. Previously, I said „*you might*“. But after [*verification by experimentation*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_307208), I've established that you *will* have to also refactor the class declaration of _`BaseConfigAPI`_  to include the newly-added _`Out`_ type parameter. Any improvement for your test on your end? Let me know? TIA.